# Google Tango Devices different horizon line

Tags: android, google-project-tango

We are having issues with one of our two tango devices. 
With one device it's really easy to create adf files and re localize. With the other it's very hard (same room, and scanning area).

Furthermore we are developing a multiplayer game by sharing the adf file. And the device who connects to the first one always has a offset in the y-axis.

Another experiment showed a quite strange behavior: 
We placed the two devices in the docking stations right next to each other, closed all apps and rebooted both devices. Then we opened the explorer app on both devices and displayed the point cloud. Oddly enough the horizon line one device is much higher than on the other. Is this normal or is on of our devices miss-calibrated/broken. 
Here are the two screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Even if these two tablets are physically at the same height level. They  haven't the same Z because their initialization at 0 happens at the start of the service. You can check this with full diagnostic menu entry.